# Opposite of ChrW in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to, given a unicode character, find out the "CharCode" for that char.

What is the opposite of ChrW in vb.net (or other code which doesnt bruteforce it)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need AscW - documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zew1e4wc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).